# How to login into Unity 2d?

Tags: unity-2d

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop. It loads Unity 3D. But, I want to login into Unity-2d. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

## 11.10

Just log-off and then choose, in your login, screen Ubuntu 2D.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## 12.04

Logoff - click the icon show and choose Unity 2D

[image]

[image]