# After logging in, nothing happens

Tags: 11.10, login

I'm new to Ubuntu and this is my first time using it. 
So basically I get the login screen and after logging in my account, I get to a screen with the wallpaper and the taskbar (at the top) and the other bar (on the left) is black. 
I'm pretty sure I installed everything correctly.

Comment: You *just* installed it?

Comment: Yes. I just installed it.

Comment: does this Q&A help?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/74300/how-to-login-into-unity-2d

Answer (score 2):

1. Get back to the log-in screen however you can. Hard reboot what ever works. Next to your name in the log-in screen click the little gear icon, and select "Ubuntu-2D".
2. Now log-in and see if it loads a usable desktop. Once you are in assuming it works, click the large dash button (Ubuntu logo) on the launcher (panel looking thing on the left side) 
   "Additional Drivers."
3. Be sure that you are connected to Internet. Somehow Ethernet is best but if you have working Wireless at this point congrats.
4. Allow the driver app to download sources.
5. Install your graphics driver and if wireless isn't working yet install the wireless driver if available.

You should be set after that.

Comment: "Ubuntu-2D" hint worked for me. Thanks!