# Ubuntu 11.10 very slow

Tags: 11.10, system

I have laptop HP 6720s. This happens when I enter top in Terminal:

> Cpu(s):  1.7%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.0%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,
>   0.0%st
>
> Mem:   2053924k total,  1837352k used,   216572k free,    56876k
>   buffers
>
> Swap:  2929660k total,       68k used,  2929592k free,  1196700k
>   cached

I have INTEL graphics card. Applications opens really slow but wireless is really fast. Operations inside applications are slow, too. I have Ubuntu for the first time, I totaly moved Windows 7 to history :) Hope Linux is not this slow usually.

Please help.

Comment: what do you mean by "wireless is really fast" compared to "applications open slow" - how are these observations related?  What "operations" are slow?

Comment: They are not related, I apologize if it sounded like that. Applications opens slow, and every operation I do in applications like Ubuntu software center is slow. I click and then I must wait a couple of seconds till operation completes. Is there any problem with my graphics cards or RAM?

Comment: Seems strange - ok, lets first see if this is a compiz issue - please login to unity-2d and see if your problem is resolved.  This Q&A should help you if you dont know how to log in to unity-2d - http://askubuntu.com/questions/74300/how-to-login-into-unity-2d

Comment: I tried that, and it is faster performance. What do you suggest then?

Comment: So I should always start unity-2d and the problem is solved then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a compiz issue then you can use Unity-2D to see if performance increases.  Unity-2D does not use compiz.

If you find that it is a compiz issue, then you are most probably affected by [this bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/861061).

This has been resolved and is awaiting testing by a larger group of users.  If this is successful the fix will be released into the main repository and you will automatically receive this as part of the Update-Manager process.  This will normally occur in a few-days/weeks after a fix is released into the proposed repository.

If you are feel you wish to contribute to the testing process, you can enable the "Proposed" repository in your software-sources. Refresh your software sources via Update-Manager and you will see new Unity packages available.  You could install these suggested packages.

Answer (score 1):

It's very annoying when people say things like what do you mean by "wireless is really fast" compared to "applications open slow". I have had various versions of Ubuntu now, and yes, 11.10 for me has fast wireless with slow applications, exactly as said. This is quite a clear description by boofighter.
These observations are obviously related, as the slowness is *not* an Internet/downloading issue.
Will also investigate Compiz.. it sped up version 11.04 for me, though was still a little slow.

Comment: more a comment than an answer to the problem