# Logging in to account on 12.04 installation leads to perpetual loop

Tags: login

The strangest thing started happening earlier this week: each time I try to log into my laptop account (ubuntu 12.04), I get a very short black screen with a few lines of text, then I get sent back to the login screen. Intriguingly enough, I can perfectly log into the guest account and into another non-admin account I had created before.
I can access the command line via ctrl+alt+F1 and log myself into my account, but then I have no clue as to how further investigate this issue.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: just a guess, but try logging in to Unity-2D instead

Comment: In case you don't know, here's how http://askubuntu.com/questions/74300/how-to-login-into-unity-2d

Comment: Thanks for input. I've tried that, but the behaviour is exactly the same: it brings me back to the login screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log in on a TTY (ctrl+alt+f1), run this:

```
sudo chown -R YOURUSERNAME:YOURUSERNAME /home/YOURUSERNAME/
```

Of course, replace YOURUSERNAME with your actual username (don't read over the semicolon).

Now, try logging in again.

Comment: Wonderful, it worked! I must have accidentally given ownership of my account to the root user.